# PHP Error Warning: curl_setopt(): Unable to access

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

i have error on use PHP Curl

Set Coockie:

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookiePath."/".$this->subClassName.'_cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookiePath."/".$this->subClassName.'_cookie.txt');
```

Error:

```
Warning: curl_setopt(): Unable to access /home/pasx/domains/pasx.xyz/public_html/bank/ssbb_cookie.txt in /home/pasx/domains/pasx.xyz/public_html/bank/General.php on line 35 
Warning: curl_setopt(): Unable to access /home/pasx/domains/pasx.xyz/public_html/bank/ssbb_cookie.txt in /home/pasx/domains/pasx.xyz/public_html/bank/General.php on line 37 SSL connect error
```

Comment: fix folder permissions? check file actually exists?

Comment: folder have 777 permissions , after run auto generate cookie files but now dont generate. i dont see cookie file

Comment: try creating empty txt files

Comment: thankyou fix this problem, now i have SSL connect error

Comment: I guess the cookie file ssbb_cookie.txt does already exist. this is may the reason the cookie cannot be saved.

Comment: try telling curl not to verify ssl certs

Comment: permission issue. what do you get from running `var_dump(shell_exec('namei -l '.escapeshellarg($this->cookiePath."/".$this->subClassName.'_cookie.txt').' 2>&1'));`  ?